# Does higher voltage and plate area cause more separation between leaves in electroscope?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, coulombs-law

Does higher voltage cause more separation between leaves in electroscope? Will higher voltage and plate area attract more charge since Q = CV.[image]

Comment: I like the diagram. Did you make that yourself?

Comment: Yes, using paint.

Comment: Thats great! I think thats worth an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Think of the voltage as an electric field and hence the stronger the electric field (and similarly larger voltage) the stronger it will push charges. Consequently, even more charge will accumulate on both leaves (of the same charge) and hence there will be a stronger "Coulombic" repulsive force between the two leaves, and hence farther difference.

Comment: Thanks, but how about plate area at the top of electroscope? Will it attract more charge?

Comment: Yes it will. However it will be opposite charge than the leaves. So if you put a +1000V on, then electrons would be attracted to the top and positive charge would be repelled to the leaves. For -1000V positive charge would be attracted to the top and the electrons would be repelled to the leaves

Comment: Does larger plate area increase capacitance or larger area give more space for electron to accumulate?